# Running 32 bit program of 64 bit Ubuntu in VirtualBox?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have a few 32 bit .elf & .out files that I would like to run, and for this purpose I installed Ubuntu 13 64-bit in VirtualBox. (I would have preferred a 32 bit distribution, but highly limited internet meant I had to dig in my friend's laptop and got just the 64-bit iso.) My host OS is Windows 10.

However running the file (via the Terminal) gives me the error "No such file or directory". However, I am able to view the details of the file using 'file filename.elf".

After Googling I found out it was because 32-bit files could not be run on 64 bit Ubuntu without additional libraries. But following the instructions in here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit did not exactly work out.

None of the libraries seemed to install properly. Example: Trying 'sudo apt-get install libc6:i386' gave me "Package libc6:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean the package is missing, has been obsoleted or is available from another source. However, the following packages replaces it: libc-bin intscripts locales tzdata.
E: package libc6 has no installation candidate"

So basically confused right now, so it would be great if anyone can give me a very basic, down-to-earth explanation of getting 32-bit executable to work on a 64 bit Ubuntu in VirtualBox.

If this is impossible, point me to a good lightweight 32-bit ubuntu emulator that can run .elf and .out files.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
apt-get install libc6-i386
```

Ref: [How to run 32-bit app in recent Ubuntu 64-bit](https://superuser.com/questions/1076730/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-recent-ubuntu-64-bit/)